# In hash sharding, is there an algorithm that enables hash partitioning twice on a UUID V1?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-partitioning

Meaning, as a real life example, first, we want to logically shard across 8 MySQL instances on the UUID V1 key, and then lastly, while accessing the table containing the UUID V1 key, we want to partition that table across 8 partitions on the same UUID V1 key.

Usually we modulus the hash key by the number of instances e.g. `key % 8` and find the bucket but afterwards, is there an algorithm to hash partition it a second time?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  No.

Long answer:

`PARTITION BY HASH` does not provide any performance that you can't get with ordinary indexing on a non-partitioned table.  Provide the `SELECTs` if you need help with indexing.

Also, UUIDs perform poorly for huge tables.  Use UUIDs if you must; otherwise avoid them.